# Make x the subject of this formula:

Tags: factoring

$$y + 2xb = \dfrac{x}{2b} + 9xb$$

workings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/524y3.jpg

I don't think I'm allowed to subtract xb from both sides like i did.

Comment: No, you can't; try solving for $x$ from $y=x\left(\dfrac1{2b}+9b-2b\right),$ and please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't say $C+xbD=E+xbF\implies C+D=E+F.$

You could say $y=x\left(\dfrac1{2b}+9b-2b\right)$ and solve for $x$ that way.

Comment: Can I say this: https://imgur.com/KGSchdH

Comment: Yes, you may say that

Comment: thank you very much for your help, J. W. Tanner.

Comment: You're welcome, @AlanMarsh

Answer (score 1):

I have to multiply by $2b$, so: $$2yb - 14xb^2 = x$$

From here, I obtain, picking up $x$: $x(14b^2+1)=2yb$. And so: $$x=\frac{2yb}{14b^2+1}$$